# In SharePoint App, What permission will be needed to bind taxonomy termstore to column of list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have SharePoint hosted app which creates list with Taxonomy Field. I want to bind term store to that column.

I tried by editing that column and try to set "Term Set Settings", but that setting sections shows empty box. I have added metadata read permission in appmanifest.
 [image]

I am deploying this app in SharePoint Online. What permissions I need to apply to app?

Answer (score -1):

Please see below link which help you
[refer this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2014/03/13/taxonomy-picker-in-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app/)